# Printing Curve Fit Function

Tags: python, numpy, printing, curve-fitting, trigonometry

I have been struggling to find a way to get the determined parameters for the curve fit function below to print. The graph properly matches my data, but I can't figure out how to get the equation it produced. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
y_data = [.99, 1, .98, .93, .85, .77, .67, .56, .46, .36, .27, .19, .12, .07, .03, .01, 0, .01, .05, .09, .16, .24, .33, .44, .55, .65, .76, .85, .93, .98, 1]
x_val = np.array(x_data)
y_val = np.array(y_data)

def fitFunc(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.sin((2* np.pi / b) * x - c) + d
    print(a, b, c, d)

plt.plot(x_val, y_val, marker='.', markersize=0, linewidth='0.5', color='green')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc, x_val, y_val)
plt.plot(x_val, fitFunc(x_val, *popt), color='orange', linestyle='--')
```

Comment: You have already implemented the equation in `fitFunc`.  The tuple `popt` contains `(a, b, c, d)`.

Comment: Remove the "print(a, b, c, d)" in fitFunc and add "print(popt)" after the call to curve_fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graphing example that uses your data, note the equation. This example uses initial parameter estimates that were manually estimated from a scatterplot of the data, the default curve_fit estimates are all 1.0 by default and those do not work well in this case.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0])
yData = np.array([.99, 1.0, 0.98, 0.93, 0.85, 0.77, 0.67, 0.56, 0.46, 0.36, 0.27, 0.19, 0.12, 0.07, 0.03, 0.01, 0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.09, 0.16, 0.24, 0.33, 0.44, 0.55, 0.65, 0.76, 0.85, 0.93, 0.98, 1.0])


def fitFunc(x, amplitude, center, width, offset):
    return amplitude * np.sin(np.pi * (x - center) / width) + offset

# these are the curve_fit default parameter estimates, and
# do not work well for this data and equation - manually estimate below
#initialParameters = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

# eyeball the scatterplot for some better, simple, initial parameter estimates
initialParameters = np.array([0.5, 1.0, 16.0, 0.5])

# curve fit the test data using initial parameters
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc, xData, yData, initialParameters)
print(fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = fitFunc(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = np.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = np.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = np.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (np.var(absError) / np.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = np.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = fitFunc(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```